# sql server xml delete two attributes at the same time

Tags: sql-server, xml, sqlxml

I found the following which shows how to delete an attribute from XML in SQL Server: [How to delete an attribute from an XML variable in sql server 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5345746/how-to-delete-an-attribute-from-an-xml-variable-in-sql-server-2008)

But I would like to delete two attributes at once. I tried something like the following:

```
UPDATE TABLE SET
  xmlField.modify('delete  (/clue_personal_auto/@attr1)[1]'),
  xmlField.modify('delete  (/clue_personal_auto/@attr2)[1]')
 WHERE compare = 357
```

But I get an error that the same column cannot be modified more than once during an update. Is there a way to delete both within once statement, or should I just run two separate updates?

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE TABLE SET
  xmlField.modify('delete (/clue_personal_auto/@*[local-name()=("attr1", "attr2")])')
 WHERE compare = 357
```

[SE-Data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/73394)