# XML attribute not removing using XML.modify

Tags: sql-server, xml, xml.modify

My `XML` is like below.

```
 <TDBUIData xmlns="http://www.somedomain.com/pace/r2.4/v1">
  <FileCreationDate>2014-07-18T13:21:48.507</FileCreationDate>
  <TDBUIDataList xmlns="">
    <PaceJobNumber>3898646894</PaceJobNumber>
    <TaskData>
      <TaskCode>Secon</TaskCode>
      <TaskAssigneeForecastFinishDate>07/16/2014</TaskAssigneeForecastFinishDate>
      <ActualFinishDate>01/01/2000</ActualFinishDate>
    </TaskData>
  </TDBUIDataList>
<TDBUIDataList xmlns="">
    <PaceJobNumber>11331313232</PaceJobNumber>
    <TaskData>
      <TaskCode>Secod</TaskCode>
      <TaskAssigneeForecastFinishDate>07/16/2014</TaskAssigneeForecastFinishDate>
      <ActualFinishDate>01/21/2000</ActualFinishDate>
    </TaskData>
  </TDBUIDataList>
</TDBUIData>
```

I need to remove `xmlns=""` attribute from all `TDBUIDataList` tags.

I am using this query, But its just not working.

```
DECLARE @XML XML            
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://www.somedomain.com/pace/r2.4/v1' )                 
Select @XML=(SELECT  GETDATE() AS FileCreationDate, CONVERT(XML,@paceXML)       
FOR XML PATH('TDBUIData'))

SET @XML.modify('delete (/TDBUIData/TDBUIDataList/@xmlns[.=""])[1]')
SELECT @XML
```

Comment: To start, you'll need to specify the namespace in your delete query. Nothing will match `/TDBUIData` as it is in a different namespace.

Comment: can you specify some example...??

Comment: This is Invalid flagging. provided answer seems to ask different issue and answers provided below are different then question by just reading question .My question was not supposed to mark as duplicate
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5345746/how-to-delete-an-attribute-from-an-xml-variable-in-sql-server-2008

Comment: You are mistaken. The question is fundamentally the same.

Comment: Correct, Fundamental is the same...But none of their answer provide answer to my question...You could go through all the answers given and then verify that...